# Is there any way to delete any node in Binary Tree without having root node refrence?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, binary-tree

[image]I was trying for this problem but not able to crack it. We have a Binary Tree and I want delete a given node from the tree but we don't have reference of root node. I am getting an idea how can we do this without having reference of root node. We do have the reference to node5, like in the image.

Comment: Do nodes have `parent` field? Do you have a reference for the node you are trying to delete?

Comment: Can you give an example of how the tree is supposed to look after the deletion?

Comment: Could you give more information about your tree structure and the node you want to remove?

Comment: @amit we dont have any field in node pointing to parent node. This is the use case for this problem.

Comment: @SantiagoVarela i have attached the image of binary tree for the reference.

Comment: Cool! I edited my answer.

Comment: I've come across a similar question in regard to linked lists during interviews.  When deleting a node, people get stuck on the idea of deleting that exact node and patching up the links.  The trick is to keep the node, but shift the data "up" toward the head (or root), and actually deleting the last (or leaf) node.

Answer (score 2):

### Update considering the new edit.

Since this is **NOT** a **Binary Search Tree**, in this case I'm assuming the node order in the tree is **not relevant** and the tree will not have duplicates, so removing `node5` will be possible with the same data structure we defined above, but we need to include a **parent node** reference (for **step 3** detailed below):

```
node {
   d: data
   leftChild: node
   rightChild: node
   parent: node
}
```

Now we can remove `node5` modifying the tree without **accessing/modifying** the **root** (`node1`).

You'll have to do the following:

> (Remember that **node 5** is also a **Binary subtree**, so after
>   modifying it, we want the whole Binary Tree to still remain one!)

1. Find `node5`'s **deepest** node. You need to traverse `node5`'s node reference as a tree.

> (*Be careful with how you pass the arguments. `root` should be a copy,
>   so that it doesn't mess with `node5`' as a root, but `level` and
>   `deepestNode` should be references.)

```
findDeepestNode(root: node, level: integer, deepestNode: node) {
    if (root != null) {
         level = level + 1
         find(root.left, level)
         if (level > deepestlevel) {
            deepestNode = root;    // node reference to the deepestNode
            deepestlevel = level;
      }
      find(root.right, level);
   }
}
```

---

Once executing this, `deepestNode` in your case will be `node7` or `node8`. It doesn't matter.

---

2. Now make `node5`'s value equal to `deepestNode`'s value. In our pseudocode:

> `node5.data = deepestNode.data` // Replacing node5's value with the deletingNode's one.

3. The tree now has a duplicate value. You still have `deepestNode`. So now you assign `deepestNode` **parent's reference** to null and delete
   `deepestNode` as a reference. **This step is the reason we need to include a parent node reference.**

### Your removal is complete!

Comment: I think the OP's question is about the case where you have to delete the root in a way that would require the pointer to the root to be changed. They assume that they have a *copy* of the pointer to the root, rather than a *reference* to a pointer to the root, so changing the *copy* of the pointer won't change the actual pointer itself.

Comment: @templatetypedef The OP said he wants to delete "a given node", but he doesn't have the reference to the root node. In no place does it say, he wants to change the root of the tree.

Comment: I was interpreting the question to mean "I have a pointer to a node in a tree. I need to remove it from the tree, but I don't necessarily have a reference pointer to the root of the tree." I suppose we should ask for a clarification?

Comment: @templatetypedef yes node which needs to be deleted, we are given the reference of that node. But i wondering about if we dont have a reference of root node, how the deletion can be performed (including adjustment of  subtree of the node which needs to be deleted)

Comment: @i_Intiution: I've update my answer. Check it out to see if it helps you.

Comment: You've got multiple different answers mashed together here, with the best one at the end.  If you could re-organize them and make them more distinct (or edit it down to just the right answer), I would upvote.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy you're right! Amended. It had become convoluted. Really appreciate the advice.

Comment: I don't think the final Note is correct, but the rest of the answer is a lot better.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy. Think about it...it is, because in a BST we have ordered values. So, we can traverse the tree, get the minimum (of the right tree) or maximum value (of the left tree) from the root tree you're deleting. That value you set to your root reference and the minimum/maximum node is deleted. You don't delete the root reference, you just substitute its value!

Comment: And what if the node you want to delete is a leaf node?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Yes, you're probably right for that case. I will change it.

Comment: @SantiagoVarela yes you answer is correct but my requirement was not to include parent note address which is the case for this problem. With the parent node address we delete any node easily.

Comment: @i_intiuition I understand...the ideal thing would be for the tree to be a self contained, cohesive and encapsulated class. In that cass, you instantiate it in an outside scope and invoke its methods, trusting that it works without having to deal with its inner details and complexity. Unfortunately, I cannot help you any further, without more details about this implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information @SantiagoVarela. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: No problem! At least we got our brains tinkering around.

Answer (score 0):

Given nothing else but the tree itself, then you'll always have to search for the node you want to remove before removing it. If you can set yourself up for success by keeping pointers to the nodes you may want to remove beforehand, then the answer could be yes!

Comment: Even if you keep a reference to the node you want to delete. How do you "search"that node in tree and then delete if accordingly without having access to its root?

Comment: It's possible if your Node implementation includes a pointer to its parent as well. If you have access to both the parents and the children of a given node then you have everything you need to remove it. Otherwise you couldn't. Sorry, should have included that in my original answer!

Comment: Even if you have a parent attribute, you would have to keep node information aside and it's unnecessary extra information for storing some data.

Comment: @ClumsySyrup this is also the restriction that we are given a tree in which node does not have field pointing to its parent. Its my bad i missed this in my question. Sorry for this.